# Fire function onInput - Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have the following Jasmine test which tries to fire a function `onInput` but it's simply not firing it.

**QUESTION**

Using a fixture, can I use as I would in standard html and expect it to find a function in included script?

This is what I'm trying:

```
// check an input cannot accept more than x characters
describe("when the page is loaded", function(){

    var fixture;

    beforeEach(function () {

        fixture += "<input id='textInput' onInput='limitLength2(this,2)'>";
        setFixtures(fixture);

    });

    it("an input should only allow x number of characters", function(){

        $('#textInput').trigger("focus").val($('#textInput').val() + '1');
        $('#textInput').trigger("focus").val($('#textInput').val() + '1');
        $('#textInput').trigger("focus").val($('#textInput').val() + '1');

        expect($('#textInput').val().length).toEqual(2);

    });

    afterEach(function () {
        fixture = "";
        fixture = null;
    });

})
```

The test fails like `Expected 3 to equal 2.`

I also added a `console.log()` to `limitLength2()` and can confirm, this is not fired.

Can this be done this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value using jQuery, the event 'onchange' does not trigger, neither does 'oninput.

You need to `.trigger('input')` after the `.val(.... + 1)` and then it should work as expected :-)

Comment: God damnit I've tried so many combinations but not that one - many thanks! Will accept when I can

Comment: @DarrenSweeney best reply ever ;-) Oftentimes it's something small like this, and it does make you go bonkers over it when you find out! Glad i was of help :-)